# Bulk update using pymongo, merging python dictionary and DB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

As an example, suppose we have the following dictionary list in memory

```
dict_list = [
  {
    'id': 1,
    'from_value_key': 'x'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'from_value_key': 'y'
  },
  {
    'id': 4,
    'from_value_key': 'z'
  }
]
```

```
db.collection
id: 1, other_key_and_values...
id: 2, other_key_and_values...
id: 3, other_key_and_values...
```

I want to apply a batch update process to the above db collections.

The contents of the db collection after updating are as follows

```
id: 1, other_key_and_values..., to_value_key: 'x'
id: 2, other_key_and_values..., to_value_key: 'y'
id: 3, other_key_and_values... #The id: 3 does not exist in the dictionary list side, so the setting of to_value_key does not occur.
#Ignore id: 4 because it exists only in the dictionary list.
```

I think it is possible to create multiple UpdateOne and use bulk_write, but is it possible to use, for example, $lookup, $unwind, $merge, etc. in the aggregation pipline to perform the update process in batches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `id` field is unique and there is a unique index built around it, you can put your documents in a `$documents` stage and `$merge` into the collection.

```
db.aggregate([
  {
    "$documents": [
      // your python dict here
      {
        "id": 1,
        "from_value_key": "x"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "from_value_key": "y"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "from_value_key": "z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "id",
      "whenMatched": "merge"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wUrVThpi_wR)

^ This won't work, as playground is yet to support `$documents`. It is just to demonstrate the syntax.